# Getting data from microservice (api) and joining it with main app data

Tags: php, database, api, design-patterns, microservices

In the client application, we moving parts of a monotith system to microservices architecture. In a very simplistic way it looks so:
- core application has its own database with products
- microservices have own databases with various objects, which may be related to products.

Scenario 1:
We want to show product "Apple" on the page, with related data from microservice. 
It's easy: just get "Apple" from core-app database and retrieve additional data for this product from microservice. Good.

Scenario 2:
We want to show a list of products with various conditions for core-app database and other conditions for the microservice database. How to do it?
Should I get - for example - 1000 products from the database (core-app) and call microservice for additional data for these products? But how? Should I send one query with 1000 ids or 1000 API calls or get data from API service in portions, for example, 10 API calls for 100 items? I don't like each of these options.

Scenario 3:
We have "Warehouse" microservice.

I want list of first 100 products sorted by name, ascending, which have flag available = true in the warehouse. How to do it? If I get 100 products from core-app db and then call API to check flag, then final list of products may be lower than 100. 
Getting list of all items available in the warehouse is a bad idea, because there may be millions of items, so execution time and API response size will be not acceptable.

Generally, I need an idea, how to merge some data from one db and some data from other DB and return it to a user view.

The app is written in PHP, but maybe some guys experienced in J2EE know solutions for these problems?

EDIT: I have found that: http://microservices.io/patterns. I will look at it closer.

Answer (score 0):

First though that comes to me is that in general, microservice should handle given bounded context/domain. So I wonder what is this 'additional' data that you want to add to products and if it also shouldn't fall under products microservice.

If you're sure it shouldn't, these are separate domains, then it's a question of your API design. If you predict to often query another microservice with 1000s of IDs, build an API that can handle 1000s of IDs (or preferably any length of the ID list).

As for scenario 3 - if I would get such task, I would create an API that handles sorting and filtering, so that all those operations that databases are good in, will be handled by databases.

In general, my pov is that API should be driven by your business needs and shouldnt constrain you in delivering high quality solution fast. So if simple CRUD API doesnt work for you (and it rarely does), just change it.